# Leave StreamReader without closing Stream

Tags: c#, azure, streamreader, azure-servicebusrelay

I'm working with the Azure Relay Service at the moment and faced a problem handling the stream. I need to use this service in a synchronous way as it is required by the software which will use this implementation.

I'm opening a stream to the service and reading the data from it with `StreamReader()`, works fine. But now I must **leave** the StreamReader **without closing** the underlying stream as I have to send an answer back to the sender.

The problem is, that I can't leave the `StreamReader()` without closing the underlying stream and its not posible to reopen the stream to send an answer back.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not leave the `StreamReader` open until you've sent the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [overload of the `StreamReader` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a `bool leaveOpen` parameter. Passing `true` prevents the `StreamReader` from closing the stream when the `StreamReader` is disposed.

> *leaveOpen*
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> **true** to leave the stream open after the StreamReader object is disposed; otherwise, **false**.

Example, using the default UTF8 encoding and 1024-byte buffer that you get with the simpler `StreamReader` constructors:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
{
    // use reader
} // stream will NOT be closed here
```

Comment: Are there any issues with leaving Stream open? I need to use the leaveOpen for `HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind()` for a .net core project. I just wanted to know whether there are any implications...

Comment: The _only_ effect of setting the `leaveOpen` flag is to stop `StreamReader.Dispose()` from calling `Dispose()` on the underlying stream. Otherwise the "implications" of leaving the stream open are the same as they would be in any other situation.

Comment: that overload is only available since .NET 4.5 though